# ¿Existen los diccionarios connotativos?

Tags: recursos, diccionarios

A veces me encuentro en la encrucijada de querer escribir algo, pero cuando lo hago trato de buscar que las mismas palabras que utilizo connoten lo que el narrador está sintiendo o trate de narrar algo diferente detrás del significado de sus palabras.

¿Existe algún diccionario de significados interpretativos o connotativos, o tengo que remitirme al uso de la interpretación etimológica?

Comment: Gracias @walen, no habia visto el DIRAE, sus ejemplos, y relacion con otras palabras o origen hace que este muy cerca de ser un diccionario tanto etimologico como de sinonimos, increible herramienta !!